# Assigning value to pandas dataframe values for unique values in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"marks": [40, 60, 90, 20, 100, 10, 30, 70 ], "students": 
                   ["Jack", "Jack", "Jack", "Jack", "John", "John", "John", "John"]}
        )

   marks  students
0  40      Jack
1  60      Jack
2  90      Jack
3  20      Jack
4  100     John
5  10      John
6  30      John
7  70      John
```

I am attempting to assign a student's average to his marks below 40 (the average will include the lowest mark).

I am aware of assigning a mark based on the `< 40` condition (in this case I assigned the lowest mark of the df to all marks below 40), like so:

```
df.loc[df["marks"] < 40, "marks"] = df["marks"].min()
```

But I am confused on how to potentially apply a lambda function on unique `student` names. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `np.where`

```
df['marks'] = np.where(df['marks'] <40, 
                       df.groupby('students')['marks'].transform('mean'), 
                       df['marks'])
    
df
Out[18]: 
   marks students
0   40.0     Jack
1   60.0     Jack
2   90.0     Jack
3   52.5     Jack
4  100.0     John
5   52.5     John
6   52.5     John
7   70.0     John
```

Comment: isn't this more or less the same a my answer? ;)

Comment: @mozway if you think so , I can delete

Comment: No, doesn't matter to me, I was just wondering for a bit if I had missed a clever trick ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can combine a `groupby` and `where`:

```
df['corrected_marks'] = df['marks'].where(df['marks']>=40,
                                          (df.groupby('students')
                                             ['marks']
                                             .transform('mean'))
                                          )
```

output:

```
   marks students  corrected_marks
0     40     Jack             40.0
1     60     Jack             60.0
2     90     Jack             90.0
3     20     Jack             52.5
4    100     John            100.0
5     10     John             52.5
6     30     John             52.5
7     70     John             70.0
```

Answer (score 1):

@mozway answer is correct. You could do it in two steps:

```
df['mean'] = df.groupby('students')['marks'].transform('mean')

df['final_marks'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['mean'] if (x['marks'] < 40) else x['marks'], axis=1)

print(df)
```

output:

```
   marks students  mean  final_marks
0     40     Jack  52.5         40.0
1     60     Jack  52.5         60.0
2     90     Jack  52.5         90.0
3     20     Jack  52.5         52.5
4    100     John  52.5        100.0
5     10     John  52.5         52.5
6     30     John  52.5         52.5
7     70     John  52.5         70.0
```

Answer (score 1):

To apply your logics on unique `student` names, you can group by `student` names by [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and get the average of each student (each group) by [`transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) on `'mean'`.  Then, you can assign the mean values to `marks` using the same mechanism in the code you tried, like below:

```
df.loc[df["marks"] < 40, "marks"] = df.groupby('students')['marks'].transform('mean')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   marks students
0   40.0     Jack
1   60.0     Jack
2   90.0     Jack
3   52.5     Jack
4  100.0     John
5   52.5     John
6   52.5     John
7   70.0     John
```

If you actually want to assign the lowest mark (instead of 'mean' mark) of each `student` to all marks below 40 for that student, you can use [`transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) on `'min'` instead:

```
df.loc[df["marks"] < 40, "marks"] = df.groupby('students')['marks'].transform('min')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   marks students
0     40     Jack
1     60     Jack
2     90     Jack
3     20     Jack
4    100     John
5     10     John
6     10     John
7     70     John
```